# How to match a specific part of an input file to that of another file so that I can copy contents from the input to the second file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dir with input files (40 total). The file names are all the same except for a number identifier.

1. Input dir example:

- File1 = msl_**gene001181**_aln.nexus
- File2 = msl_**gene001650**_aln.nexus
- File3 = msl_**gene001976**_aln.nexus
- etc.

I have a second dir files (40 total) named with the same number identifiers.

2. Second dir example:

- File1 = bipartitions_**gene001181**.nexus
- File2 = bipartitions_**gene001650**.nexus
- File3 = bipartitions_**gene001976**.nexus
- etc.

I need to append information from my input files into the files of the second dir with the same matching number identifiers.

For example, information from *msl_gene001181_aln.nexus* needs to go into *bipartitions_gene001181.nexus*.

I just do not know how to write the code so that the contents of one file get appended to the correct file in the second directory. This is the last part of a larger script that I am writing. I got stuck at the end.

I appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

- Logical steps:

1. Read into my input files.
2. Once I am able to read into my input files, I need to extract specific lines of text.
3. Take the extracted lines of text and **append** them to the outfile with the same matching number identifier in the filename.
4. Code needs to tell the computer that the information from the input file with *gene001181* in its file name needs to be appended to the output file that also contains *gene001181*.

```
import os

path_to_input_data = "path/"
input_dir = os.listdir(path_to_input_data)

output_dir = "output_dir"
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
os.makedirs(output_dir)

for input_files in input_dir:
    if input_files.endswith(".nexus"):
        input_file_path = os.path.join(path_to_input_data, input_files)
        input_nexus_files = open(input_file_path, 'r')
        with open(os.path.join(output_dir, file), 'a') as output:
            for lines in nexus_file:
                if lines.startswith("begin data"):
                    output.write(lines)
                    try:
                        while "end" not in lines:
                            next_line = next(nexus_file)
                            output.write(next_line)
                    except StopIteration:
                        pass
```

This bit of code extracts the information that I need, and it creates new output files with the input information in the output dir. I would like to extract my lines of text from my input files, and put them in the files that are **already** in my output dir. The input files and output files have matching numbers. I just do not know how to write that part in my code.

I apologize for the lack of info in my original post, and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Okay, so what do you imagine are the logical steps to the problem? Are you able to write any relevant code at all? Where exactly do you get stuck? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service; you are expected to put in some original effort.

Comment: Anyway, it isn't clear what you mean about "copy/pasting" data from one file to another. What should happen to the existing data in the file?

Comment: I absolutely understand that SO is not a code-writing service. I apologize. I'll provide the logical steps that I want to occur, and then some relevant code that can be built upon. I did not want my post to be too long. I will edit my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the output file name based on your input file.

```
>>> input_file_name = 'msl_gene001181_aln.nexus'
>>> gene = input_file_name.split('_')[1]
>>> output_file_name = f'bipartitions_{gene}.nexus'
>>> output_file_name
'bipartitions_gene001181.nexus'
>>>
```

Use os.path.basename to get only the filename from the input_file_path:

```
>>> os.path.basename('/some/random_dir/msl_gene001181_aln.nexus')
'msl_gene001181_aln.nexus'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe that this is exactly what I wanted to know how to do. I will have to test this out tomorrow, but I will go ahead and give you the "accepted answer".

Comment: Thanks. You can test it out now, I will be online for another hour. If you need any help or have any confusion I can resolve that. Else leave a comment tomorrow and I will reply when I get back to it!

Comment: Have to go to bed, but I will for sure test this out tomorrow. I will report back if it works in my script.

Comment: I would like to confirm that your solution worked lllrnr101! Once I figured out how to write it into my code it worked like a charm. I really appreciate your help, and now I've added another Python tool to my toolkit.